# cannot extract from stringstream after clearing

Tags: c++11, stringstream

I would like to extract "World" from the `stringstream` into the `string` strB but the string strB remains empty. Any suggestions on how I can fix this and why this is happening ?

```
int main()
{
        std::string strA;
        std::string strB;

        std::stringstream parser("Hello");
        parser >> strA;
        std::cout << strA;

        parser.clear();
        parser << "World";
        parser >> strB;
        std::cout << strB; // Why cant i extract from parser again ? ? Why is strB empty ?     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `parser.clear()`  you must do `parser.str("")` to clear the buffer (whereas `clear()` resets the state flags, but not the data content).